# Automatically print testcase name and display stdout in ScalaTest via Intellij and/or maven

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

From the title my intent should be clear:

```
  test("some test") {
      // run something
       println("print something")
  }
```

Any way to override default behavior of scalatest to view the testname and view the stdout? We use IntelliJ and Maven - so info on either one and/or both would be helpful.  Note: an `extra` credit would be to display stdout only in case of testing errors.